# VisualState storyboard in a Canvas desn't work inside a Grid

Tags: canvas, uwp, grid

I have a Textblock animation that works by itself if it's inside a canvas, but it doesn't work if I put the canvas inside a Grid. It's possible to make it work/work arround? I'm missing something to make it work?

```
  <Grid Width="3200" Height="99">
    <Canvas Height="70" Width="3200" Margin="-900,0,0,0">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="States">
                <VisualState x:Name="Left">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="-100" Duration="0:0:2" From="1500" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <StateTrigger x:Name="desplazamiento" IsActive="true"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <!-- Offset the text using a TranslateTransform. -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock"  Text="Text going throught animation" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,-20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="33" Canvas.Top="36" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

It does works if I delete the Grid tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VisualStateManager` will impact only inner elements and should be placed right after first grid inside control. Try this:

```
<Grid Width="3200" Height="99">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="States">
            <VisualState x:Name="Left">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" To="-100" Duration="0:0:2" From="1500" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger x:Name="desplazamiento" IsActive="true"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Canvas Height="70" Width="3200" Margin="-900,0,0,0">

        <!-- Offset the text using a TranslateTransform. -->
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock"  Text="Text going throught animation" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,-20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="33" Canvas.Top="36" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```